# React - make input appear with text selected

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-ref

I have a functional component, that uses hooks.

```
const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false); 
...
return (
      ... 
     {editMode && <input value="Some value">} 
}
```

When editMode is changed to true  - the input field is appearing and I want it to appear with already selected text inside of it. How can I do this?

---

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) and fire a function to select text

Comment: use local state for input value, it will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `useRef` hook to create a ref and put it on your input element, and use the `useEffect` hook to run a function every time `editMode` changes. If `editMode` is `true`, you can invoke the `select` method on the `ref.current` element.

**Example**

```js
const { useState, useRef, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("Some value");
  const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (editMode) {
      ref.current.select();
    }
  }, [editMode]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setEditMode(!editMode)}>Toggle edit</button>
      <div>
        {editMode && (
          <input
            ref={ref}
            value={value}
            onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: i do `ref.current.select();` but not work for me